# Next invoice in json format

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I understand that there is an api to get the next invoice in PDF and excel format.

Is there an api to get the next invoice in json format?

Answer (score 0):

there are several methods to get the next invoice:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNextInvoiceTopLevelBillingItems
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNextInvoiceTotalAmount
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNextInvoiceTotalRecurringAmount
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNextInvoiceTotalRecurringTaxAmount
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNextInvoiceTotalTaxableRecurringAmount

I recomend you to review the documentation:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account

Regards

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick response. i have go through the docs and i think the attached URI gets me only the nextInvoiceTopLevelBillingItems. But i need all the associated chilldren for each of those topLevelBillingItems too. I need all these details with one rest call and so  thought of getting the next invoice would be a right option to go with. i tried getAllBillingItems but that is giving me internal error and i don't want to go with resultLimit option which would require making multiple rest calls.

Comment: you can use objectMask to fetch more information such as the children (e.g. mask[children ]) see http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-Masks for more information

Comment: yep, got it. i was about to add the same comment. thanks a lot.